# An Android Service with own process doesn't do what I need it to do. (loop and execute somthing every five seconds)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-service

Im trying to make my service send the phone's coordinates to my server every 5 secs,
and I have no idea why isnt it working.

(Though it does work on a non-service activity. (when an OnClick method is called - A button is clicked.

that is why the fact that its not working within the service is weird.)
This is my code:

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
                // I Dont Know what this method does.
                Execute();
                return null;
        }
        String lat="", lon="";
        public void Execute()
        {
                new PostAsyncTask().execute();
        }

        public void ReNewCoordinates(){
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // Define a listener that responds to location updates
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                    lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
                    lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
                }
                        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle extras) {}};
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                }
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate();
            ReNewCoordinates();

            //new PostAsyncTask().execute();
        }

        public void postData(String la, String lo) {
                try
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.myserver.com/insert.php");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user","100nir100"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", lon));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", GetAddress(lat, lon)));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity form;
        form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair);
        form.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair,"UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {                        

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            int status=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();//200=success 300=redirection 400=client error 500 = server error
            if(status==200)
            {
                HttpEntity e=response.getEntity();
                String data=EntityUtils.toString(e);


                   Integer x= Integer.valueOf(data.trim());//very important to use trim
                    if(x==1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Sucssess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(x!=1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Unsucssessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }                    

                        Toast.makeText(this, "Unsucssessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }              


            }
    catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception

        }
}

        public String GetAddress(String lat, String lon)
        {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
            String ret = "";
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lon), 1);
                if(addresses != null) {
                    Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");
                    for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    ret = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                }
                else{
                    ret = "No Address returned!";
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                ret = "Can't get Address!";
            }
            return ret;
        }



    class PostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
         protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
             postData(lat, lon);
                        return true;
         }

         protected void onPreExecute() {
             // show progress dialog
         }


             protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
                 // hide  progress dialog
             }
         }


        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                //new PostAsyncTask().execute();
                new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {

            while(true){
                new PostAsyncTask().execute();
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                 }
        }).start();
                return Service.START_STICKY;
          }
        public void OnStart()
        {
                Execute();
        }

        public void OnDestroy()
        {
                super.onDestroy();
                //Thread.stop();

        }

}
```

So how can I make the service do it every 5 secs?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I dont think the problem is the runnable/thread. I tried to use postDelayed and it didnt help. The problem is within the service. Even if i try to run it once, on the OnCreate();, it does not send the information to the server, while in a non-service activity, it DOES work.

Comment: Just an advice... Don't post data every 5 second, instead you can check location every 5 second, if it isn't changed since last check don't send it. If it is changed more than a threshold, send it.